# Strange, regex.split Method matches one null element

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"[+-]");
    string[] substrings = rx.Split(expression);
```

expression = "-9a3dcbh-3bca-4ab4cf-3hc" //This is the iput string
I want to split that string between + or -.
My VS debugger shows substring array like this:
substrings[0] = null //???Why 
substrings[1] = 9a3dcbh
substrings[2] = 3bca
substrings[3] = 4ab4cf
substrings[4] = 3hc

Why is the first element of arry null, is it because I am matching +-, and there is no + in my input string?

Comment: Correction, first element is not null, it is ""

Comment: In string.Split you can use the option RemoveEmptyEntries, but I don't believe Regex.Split has that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because split eliminates the delimiter, and returns the string before and after the delimiters, in this case there are no characters before the delimiter, thus the first value is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

[C# Regex.Split - Subpattern returns empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735177/c-regex-split-subpattern-returns-empty-strings).  The first answer has a great explanation

You could try this:

```
     string split_string = "-3243+324-32-2343";
     string[] nums = split_string.Split(new char[] { '-', '+' },
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```